# Запрет запуска программ

Tags: windows

Господа, доброго времени суток!

Подскажите бесплатное ПО для блокировки/запрета запуска программ в Windows (XP,7).Нужно что бы сам софт был защищен паролем, и неплохо бы с удаленным управлением.

LP и GP не подходит в моей ситуации.

Comment: > LP и GPЭто что такое? Чем штатные средства не подходят?File > Properties > Security > Advanced security settings > Permissions > Change permissions

Comment: lp = local policy, gp = group policy наверное)

Comment: @thunder, вы правы)@Flammable, да, как вариант. Но нужно из под непривилегированного пользователя этим рулить. Как цель - директор подразделения должен самостоятельно разрешать программы для сотрудников. У директора нет локальных и доменных полномочий.

Comment: Для осмысления (может не правильно выразились...): непривилегированный пользователь не может ничего запретить тем кто на локальных компьютерах работает с привилегиями. Да и что бы что либо запретить, все равно надо иметь локальные привилегии.

Comment: Хм, это "Но нужно из под непривилегированного пользователя этим рулить. Как цель - директор подразделения должен самостоятельно разрешать программы для сотрудников. У директора нет локальных и доменных полномочий." смахивает на превышение служебных полномочий. Либо налицо полное нарушение системы безопасности, либо IT подразделение не выполняет свои функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо, проблема решилась правильным способом =) Объяснил руководству что правильно - использование групповых политик, и что если начальство хочет что либо заблокировать, то все должно рулиться через админов. Упирались но согласились)

Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

"`my lockbox control panel`" - эта программа не защищает паролем, но делает ещё лучше. просто собери все программы в одной папке и через программу, которую я тебе посоветовал скрой их. При запуске шифровальной проги будет пароль запрашивать, который будешь знать только ты. Я с помощью этой программы все файлы скрыл.

Answer (score -1):

Любой архиватор с паролем и скриптом запуска!

Comment: Прошу прощения, неверно понял вопрос!